# How to resize image to fit all the aspect ratio using jCrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop for resizing an image with aspect ratio 1. For most cases works well, however in some cases when the image is widther I can't select all the image. What kind of action can I do for select the whole content of the image?

[image]

My code is:

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('#jimage').attr('src', e.target.result);
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     $('#jimage').Jcrop({
        onSelect:    showCoords,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        bgColor:     '#2e7cce',
        bgOpacity:   .4,
        boxWidth: 500,
    });
}}
```

I tried to add some zoom implementations I looked in the web however the zoom affects the area of selection and the result is the same. I need to be able to select all the content of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting the `aspectRatio: 1` means you always want a square selection, you would not be able to select the whole image if the image is rectangular(the height is bigger than width or vice versa).

One solution is to remove `aspectRatio: 1` this would allow free-form cropping.

Another solution is to scale the image to a square before passing it on to Jcrop.

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  $('#jimage').attr('src', e.target.result);
  width = $('#jimage').width();
  height = $('#jimage').height();
  if(height > width )
    $('#jimage').width(width * (height/width));
  else if(width > height)
    $('#jimage').height(height * (width/height));
}
```